# Numpy: specify `astype` output buffer

Tags: arrays, numpy, buffer, dtype

I am trying to read 8-bit integer values from a file into a `numpy` array and convert them into 32-bit floats.  I ***really need*** to write these 32-bit floats to a particular memory buffer (I am using shared memory for multiprocessing).  I am trying to figure out if there is a way to do the type conversion straight into my pre-allocated buffer for 32-bit floats without creating a temporary array.

For instance, if there was an `astype` method with an output argument, like:

```py
num_samples = 100
raw_buffer = bytearray(num_samples)
with open(filepath, 'rb') as f:
    f.readinto(raw_buffer)
int_array = np.frombuffer(raw_buffer, dtype=np.int8)

float_buffer = bytearray(num_samples * 4)

int_array.astype(np.float32, out=float_buffer)
```

Is there a way to do something like this?

Comment: `astype` does not take a `out` parameter, https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html.  Why do you need to use this preallocated buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure this is what you expected but I am pretty sure the result is the one you want.

```py
a=np.arange(3, dtype=np.int8)
buf=bytearray(12)
b=np.frombuffer(buf, dtype=np.float32)
b[:]=a

# Note that it does write in the buffer
buf
# bytearray(b'\x00\x00`A\x00\x00pA\x00\x00\x80A')
import struct
struct.unpack('fff', buf)
# (14.0, 15.0, 16.0)
```

And from a timing perspective, on my PC, just running `a.astype(np.float32)` on a 10000 byte array takes 4.6 μs. And running `b[:]=a` takes 4.1 μs. So if unecessary copy is your concern, apparently, that solution isn't doing more operations than `astype`.

Note, that replacing `a.astype(np.float32)` by `a.astype(np.float32).copy()` (just to estimate how much an extra copy cost) make the timing 8.2 μs.
So apparently, a copy cost 4 μs. So I don't think there is any unnecessary copy in my `b[:]=a`, or else it wouldn't cost only 4.1 μs (there is the implicit copy/conversion from the uint8 buffer to the float32 buffer, but that one can't be avoided, and you didn't expected it to be avoided. So I am quite confident that nothing more than your virtual `astype(dtype=np.float32, out=buffer)` would do is happening here.

Comment: Thank you.  I think you are correct that this does what I want.  It was a bit unintuitive imo because I got used to passing an output parameter to numpy functions.  Indeed, it seems like relying on the implicit type conversion when assigning to a numpy array is the way to go.